# updatable and insertable on @MapKeyColumn for Map based @ElementCollection

Tags: jpa-2.0

I have two examples for mapping an `@Embeddable` with Map.

http://hwellmann.blogspot.com/2010/07/jpa-20-mapping-map.html

http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/MapKeyColumn

One says

```
@MapKeyColumn(..., insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

And the other says

```
@MapKeyColumn(...) // without insertable = false, updatable = false
```

Can anybody please tell me which one is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only second one of your examples is about mapping [@Embeddable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html). First one is about `Map<String, String>` element collection - no embeddables included.

Reason why insertable and updatable are set to false in second one  is that 'language' property in element collection is accessible via both key of the map and value of the map. Having one out of those as readonly saves from conflicting data in key of the map and in ''language' property.

Setting insertable and updatable to false is not needed for `Map<String, String>` because only key of the map is mapped only once.

Comment: So, `<String, String>` is ok with `@MapKeyColumn` and `<String, @Embeddable>` should be ok with '`@MapKeyColumn(u=f, i=f)`? Then I must go for `<String, String>`

Comment: Wit <String, String> you do not have have two mappings to same persistent attribute, with Embeddable it is possible when key of map is one of the attributes of Embeddable. Likely going for <String, String> is not correct way if you feel like relation to Embeddable is needed.

Comment: Wow, now I'm so clear why `updatable=false, insertable=false` needed when `<Basic, Embeddable>`. Vielen Dank! Is it possibly true that those attributes not needed when the map key is not one of `Embeddable`?

Comment: You are welcome. If in your case key of the map is not one of the attributes of Embeddable value, you do not need to guard it with updatable=false and insertable=false.